# Set Visual Studio Code as default git editor inside a Docker dev container

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, editor

Basically my problem is that when working on a development container and trying to set vscode as the git default editor, the terminal won't detect vscode (this is expected behaviour because the main goal of the dev containers is developing in isolation).

[image]

Is there a way to set vscode as the default editor inside a development container?

Answer (score -2):

Note: this is more a question about setting up containers than it is one about setting up Git.

You'd need to have that editor available inside the container, and then while in the container, tell Git to use that editor.  That's all very straightforward: just set `core.editor` appropriately, and set up whatever command line path variable you might need appropriately as well if and as necessary.  So we're just left with the puzzle of how to make this the default.

The answer to that is easy too, though.  To make it the *default*, make sure that the container's Git configuration defaults are set that way.

The defaults for Git are:

- the configuration specified by the system (`git config --system --list`; note that this produces an error message showing where the file is, if the file does not exist; add `--show-origin` if it does, to find its path-name), but
- overridden by user `--global` (`git config --global --list`), but
- overridden by current repository (`git config --list`), but
- overridden by command line and/or environment settings.

Since the *system* config and *user global* config files can be set up via Docker mounts, these are the obvious places to put the defaults.  Simply bind-mount something appropriate.  See [the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) for details.  Most current Docker systems allow bind-mount for a single file, but if yours doesn't, consider bind-mounting your entire home directory.

Comment: The dev container setup is very poorly documented by Microsoft, but basically it works like this: VSCode on the developer's machine talks to VSCode Server on Docker Host which acts as a proxy to another VSCode Server which runs inside the container. It's definitely possible to get user input on the container side from the developer's VSCode (see `credential.helper` section that VSCode Server adds to .gitconfig when attaching to a container), but replacing `core.editor` like this could be very tricky.